# PHP array from true/false to 0/1

Tags: php, arrays

This must be pretty simple to do, but I can't seem to get it working.
My code:

```
// a, b, c are true or false
$arr = array($a, $b, $c);
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if ($value == "false") {
        $value = 0;
    }
    elseif ($value == "true") {
        $value = 1;
    }
}

// Now I want $a to be either 0 or 1. Right now $value is 0 or 1.
echo $a; -> true/false
echo $value; -> 0/1
```

So how can I make $a 0/1 and the next time $b 0/1 etc.?

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to achieve? Are `$a`, `$b`, and `$c` (or their equivalents in your real code) actually separate variables, or can they be treated as part of an array? This code seems to be put them into an array but then expect to take them back out as separately named variables somehow?

Comment: They are separate variables, but I don't want to check each variable for true or false. What I'm trying to achieve is doing this in a faster way...just don't know how. The output should also be separate variables.

Comment: "Faster" how? If the variables are separate, then you should process them separately. If you want to operate on them all at once, put them in an array.

Comment: I know, that's why I put them in array. But how can I get them out of the array and return just $a again with the changed value? It's about 20 variables, that's why I don't want to do this separately

Comment: But that's my point: why take them back out of the array? Why not just use them as an array - perhaps an associative array like `array('a' => $a, 'b' => $b)` etc?

Comment: Cause afterwards I want the insert the values from the variables in my Mysql database. And that won't work with true or false, only with 1 or 0...

Comment: You misunderstand my question. I understand why you want to convert values to `0` or `1`, but I don't understand why you want to "magically" have that `0` or `1` assigned back to the original variable (`$a`, `$b`, etc) rather than having an array containing the converted versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, I'm unclear why you would want code that operates on multiple variables in the same way that couldn't simply treat them as an (associative) array of values.

Consequently, **I don't recommend this code as a pattern for anyone to use**. However, what you are looking for can be achieved using *references*. Assigning by reference in PHP means making two variables point to the same thing - one is not a reference *to* the other, they are both references to an unnamed piece of memory.

In your case, you need to do this twice: first, when you put the separate variables into the temporary array, you want to make that array contain references to those same variables, not just their values. Secondly, `foreach` (or `array_walk`, etc) will also take the *values* from the array unless you explicitly assign by reference with the appropriate syntax.

So sprinkling `&` in the appropriate places in your original code, you get this:

```
$a = 'true';
$b = 'false';
$c = 'true';

// $a, $b, $c are strings containing 'true' or 'false'

// Step 1: make an array whose elements are joined as references to $a, $b, $c
$arr = array(&$a, &$b, &$c);

// Step 2: loop over the array, taking a reference to each of its elements, not just the values
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    if ($value == "false") {
        $value = 0;
    }
    elseif ($value == "true") {
        $value = 1;
    }
}
// Step 2b: after looping by reference, $value will still refer to one of the variables in the array
// this is often a cause of bugs later, so unsetting it is a good habit
unset($value);

// Did it work?
echo "A: $a; B: $b; C: $c";
```

[Here is a live demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ht3t5O) showing that the output is "A: 1; B: 0; C: 1 ".

To repeat again, heavy use of references like this is **not** generally a good coding pattern, in my opinion, as it makes for code that is hard to follow and debug.

Comment: Somehow there's some miscommunication between us, but unset($value) did make it work! So thank you very much!

Comment: @Nick The `unset($value)` is not the main difference from the code you posted. The important thing is the use of references, which you did not have at all. I still think simply using `$arr` directly, rather than trying to magically write back to `$a`, would be a much better approach.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// Callback function, pass reference to item in array
function callback(&$val)
{
    // If $val is true, make it 1, else make it 0
    $val = $val ? 1 : 0;
}

$array = array(true, true, false);

array_walk($array, 'callback');

print_r($array);
// Output: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 0 )
```

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's question (whether or not its the right question) of how to get `$a` to be assigned back as well. It's also not really worth working with callbacks when you could just use `foreach`, which can also take its argument by reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array_map('intval', array($a, $b, $c));
```

$arr will then contain the integer values of $a, $b, and $c.

Comment: Are you sure they are actual boolean values and not strings?

Comment: Yups, they come from a checkbox. When I do this:
if ($a== "false") {
 $a= 0;
}
elseif ($a== "true") {
 $a= 1;
}

It will work...

Comment: This will not modify your array in place. You need to overwrite it with the return value from `array_map`.

Comment: If `$value == "false"` works, then it is a string, not a boolean. A simple cast will not suffice, you will need to use an `if` statement or `? :` construct.

Comment: `(bool)"false" === true` and `(bool)"true" === true`! Strings with `strlen() > 0` are **always true**

Answer (score 0):

Foreach loop can use your key/value as reference:

```
$arr = array($a, $b, $c);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $value = ($value == "true") ? 1 : 0;
}
```